# Search and Replace Specific Pattern in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have strings that look like this:

`@N05/3835412983/academy-of-sciences.html`

Where `3835412983` and `academy-of-sciences.html` will be different throughout the database table called `wp_4_posts` in a column called `post_content`.

Is there a wildcard search that I can do to preserve the unique id between the two `/` and strip `*.htm*`?  Everything to the left of the `@05` cannot change.  The numbers between the `/` need to be preserved.  And the item after the second `/` can be stripped entirely.

Doing it manually and there's hundreds that need this done to.

For the above, the end result would be:

`@N05/3835412983/`

And that result would be written back into the database.

Comment: Do you want a search or to extract the value?  Please show what results you are looking for.

Comment: Added some more info for clarity -- sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the middle element, then you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(str, '/', 2), '/', -1)
```

This extracts the second element.

Based on the edit, you seem to want:

```
select concat(substring_index(str, '/', 2), '/')
```

If you want to update the value, then:

```
update t
    set str = concat(substring_index(str, '/', 2), '/');
```

Comment: I'm a mySQL dunce -- would I just login to the mysql shell and type those things?  How do I get to the database -> table -> column?  I don't want to corrupt anything.

Answer (score 0):

update specific string then should use `replace()` function

Syntax:-

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name =
REPLACE(column_name,'OLD_STRING','NEW_STRING')
WHERE column_name = 'your condtition';
```

in your case:-

```
UPDATE wp_4_posts
SET post_content =
REPLACE(post_content,'@N05/3835412983/academy-of-sciences.html','@N05/3835412983/');
```

if you want result based on condition

```
UPDATE wp_4_posts
SET post_content =
REPLACE(post_content,'@N05/3835412983/academy-of-sciences.html','@N05/3835412983/')
WHERE column_name = "values";
```